# Instert new line in text using a value read from an excel file in r plot?

Tags: r, excel

I need to add  a title with one word in a line and another word ina new line. Consider the code below for example:

```
plot(rnorm(100), main="First line\nSecond line")
```

This gives the plot like this:

[image]

Now what if the title is read from a saved excel file? I have saved my data to an excel file (`mydata`) and read it with `read.xlsx` using package `xlsx`. The title is saved in variable `title` with value `First line\nSecond line`. Now to insert the title, I use the code below:

```
plot(rnorm(100), main=mydata$title[1])
```

But the plot looks like this:

[image]

I think for having the new line in the title, either I should use another value in the excel file or another code to insert it in the plot. Any ideas?

Here is the output of `mydata$title`:

```
[1] "First\\nSecond"  "First\\nSecond1" "First\\nSecond2" "First\\nSecond3"
[5] "First\\nSecond4"
```

Comment: Can you provide an output of `mydata$title`?

Comment: Depends a lot on the format of your title text in Excel file. Like do we insert linebreak after second white space or perhaps after second capital letter?

Answer (score 0):

`mydata$title[1]` should be `"First\nSecond"` instead of `"First\\nSecond"`. Something like this should work:

```
title1 <- c("First\\nSecond", "First\\nSecond1", "First\\nSecond2",
           "First\\nSecond3", "First\\nSecond4")
title2 <- c("First\nSecond", "First\nSecond1", "First\nSecond2",
            "First\nSecond3", "First\nSecond4")

plot(rnorm(100), main = title1[1]) # doesn't work
plot(rnorm(100), main = title2[1]) # works
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I know I should use `\n` for inserting new line, but this works just for typing in data in R consul. I'm looking for the way I should save data into an excel file so that it makes R to insert new line.

Comment: I see. `cat(mydata$title[1])` can be useful here but I don't know how to get a character of its output.